# Taking different Inputs in single line of Python

Tags: python, input

I am trying to take input from a single line in Python but it's not working.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "solution.py", line 4, in <module>
a = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 4'
```

Code:

```
q = int(input())
lis = []
for i in range(q) :
  a = int(input())
  print(a)
  if(a==1) :
    b = int(input())
    lis.append(b)
  else :
    print("Do Nothing")
```

In this code for a given integer i.e.,q.

I have to take two inputs and if the first integer is 1 then we have to add the second input to the array.

Form input:

```
5
1 4
1 9
```

If input of first line is 1, we have to add 4 to list. I am unable to take input in line 1 as only 1 it is taking both 1 4.

Comment: What integer is `1 4` supposed to be?

Comment: This is not a single integer, it's a input consisting of two integers 1 & 4 and we have to deal with them separately and add 4 to list

Comment: Or in other words, *why* is the second input `1 4` if you want it to be a second integer.

Comment: Also, if you use Python 2, use `raw_input()`, because plain `input()` interprets the string; try typing `exit()` and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Split the input, then convert to int, then do whatever

```
a = input().split()
a=[int(x) for x in a]
#a is now a list of ints
....#do other stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the most basic way of doing it

```
string = input()  # Read Input as string
print(string)

str_array = string.split(" ")  # Split the string
print(str_array)

int_arr = [int(i) for i in str_array]  # Parse the individual strings to int
print(int_arr)
```

**Output**

```
1 56 9 87 7
['1', '56', '9', '87', '7']
[1, 56, 9, 87, 7]
```

If you really want the most pythonic way of doing it

```
int_arr = [int(i) for i in input().split(" ")]
```